# Solr managed-schema for nested objects

Tags: solr, nested, documents

I'm trying to create nested documents in solr, and I'm having some troubles.

I need to know how to define the managed-schema file, and I'm not sure at all about how to do.

After a lot of investigation i found a way creating the nested document like this:

`<document name="sample" stored="true"> 
  <entity name="item" query="select * from item"> 
  <field pk="ID" name="Id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
  <field column="SAMPLEATR" name="SampleAtr" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
  </entity> 
</document>`

And now I don't see any error when trying to insert document, but while querying I'm not able to find the information.

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you've changed is the data import handler's definition - it's not the schema that Solr uses. Have you seen Yonik's [Nested Objects in Solr](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/)? It's important to know the limitations and implementation of how child documents works. It's usually a good idea to try to avoid nested documents if possible.